# can I spoof a computer name on a wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking

is there a way to spoof a computer name on a wifi network?
there is a lot of tools for mac adresses but none for this.

I know i could change it by rebooting but I don't want to have to reboot.

Thanks.

example of the view from my router :
[image]

Comment: It's trivial to change a computers name.

Comment: I don't change it because it requires a reboot, I want to appear with an other computer name on the network

Comment: There is no such thing as a "computer name" on a network.  This is way too vague.

Comment: You asked if it was possible to spoof the computers name the answer is you don't need to spoof it just change the name if the computer.  What problem are you trying to solve where your required to have a certain computer name?

Comment: For what purpose?  What name-resolution method are you using?  Where do you want this name to show up?  You need to step back and figure out what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: post edited, computer name are clearly visible on the router and blacklisting is based on those rather than mac adress, rebooting to change a computer name is bothersome

Comment: Are you sure that blacklisting is really by computername, and the router is not just giving you a friendly name tied to a MAC address?

Comment: yes because I can recognize those names, my iphone name is avalon and it's in the list, I tried spoofing my mac adress and was still blacklisted because the computer name was the same (btw it's a consumer routeur called a "livebox" made by a internet access provider called "orange")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the answer is no.

The way computer names function on a network they are registered with the next in line DNS server (usually a router). Not to mention you'll most likely not be able to even get the OS to change to the same name as when you go to change your computer name your OS will surely throw some NetBIOS error that the name is already in use.

So spoofing a computer name itself is not technically feasible. When you change the computer name of the machine you're on (for whatever reason) the DNS server that the network is talking to is going to continue to serve information to the original computer because the computer you're on was not able to register as that computer name. If you're looking into some higher level of IT tomfoolery then look into "wifi man in the middle" tools.

Comment: I found a way to hide it, if done while disconnected from the router and while also changing the mac adress then the router will give you a random computer name, allowing you to get through the routeur blacklisting

Comment: command is "net config server /hidden:yes" to hide your computer name. command prompt should be runned as administrator

Comment: @sliders_alpha That's a weak method of blacklisting of that modem ;)